# Resources in C# MSVS

Tags: c#, resources

I follow the instructions here [How to create and use resources in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-c-net-vs-2008/90699#90699)

However when i do Properties.Resources.Name; I get "The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context". Its driving me nuts bc i tried multiple things and googled and could not find a solution.

The resource is in the same project i am using. The project is 1 form. and the code is in Form1_Load

Comment: Are you using the same namespace throughout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure there there are no namespace issues. The fully qualified name of the Resources class would be `YourProject.Properties.Resources`, so if something has caused the Form to be placed in a different namespace from your Properties class, you would need to use the fully qualified name to access it from the form. Use the Object Browser to browse your solution and figure out what the namespace of your Properties class is.

Comment: It looks like since i had a 2nd prj i need to do PrjName.Properties.Resources.Name. The obj browser help me figure that out, thanks.