# Access localized resource strings without creating an instance of 'ResourceManager'?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, localization, resourcemanager

I have created some resource files to hold strings. I am displaying a `MessageBox` by pointing it directly at a resource file named `TestLocalResource` and a resource string named `ThisIsMyTest` by simply referencing the resource string like this:

```
TestLocalResource.ThisIsMyTest
```

Now this does appear to work. But this leaves me wondering that by referencing the resource string this way, will I always be accessing the *default* resource file (e.g., `TestLocalResource.resx`) rather than its German version (e.g., `TestLocalResource.de-DE.resx`)?

So instead, do I have to use `ResourceManager`? If so, how does `ResourceManager` know the current language (**culture**)? Will I need to explicitly set it?

This is how I think I would need to use `ResourceManager`:

```
ResourceManager resmgr =
    new ResourceManager("MyApplication.MyResource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

But I'm hoping that there is a way to access localized resource strings in a more convenient fashion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to use the ResourceManager explicitly.
Have a look here: http://geekswithblogs.net/mapfel/archive/2008/11/01/126465.aspx
To learn how to change the culture to use during runtime, see the [second comment](http://geekswithblogs.net/mapfel/archive/2008/11/01/126465.aspx#435744) in the link:

```
switch (comboBox1.Text)
{
    case "neutral":
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("");
        break;
    case "en-GB":
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        break;
    case "de-DE":
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        break;
}

string messageText = Messages.MsgSampleText;
MessageBox.Show(messageText);
```

Comment: It is important to note that the approach outlined in the referenced article and in your answer assumes the use of Visual Studio. I inspected `Messages.Designer.cs` (which is created by Visual Studio along with `Messages.resx`) and noted that it incorporates calls to `ResourceManager`. So, `ResourceManager` is indeed involved but the programmer does not need to access an instance of that class explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In the [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/mapfel/archive/2008/11/01/126465.aspx) referenced by @Daniel Hilgarth in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5246682/1497596), the author indicates that the resource files named `Messages.resx` and `Images.resx` should each be created in the `Properties` folder. (The `Properties` folder is also the location where Visual Studio places its general-purpose resource file named `Resources.resx`.)

I found that Visual Studio 2013 would not allow me to create and place `Messages.resx` in the `Properties` folder by right-clicking the `Properties` node in Solution Explorer. Instead, here's what I did:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the Project node.
2. Select Add => New Item... => Resources File => `Messages.resx`. Result: Visual Studio places `Messages.resx` in the *Project* folder.
3. In Solution Explorer, drag `Messages.resx` to the `Properties` node.

As @Daniel indicates, a new class named `Messages` will now conveniently provide you with access to your resource strings. Note that `Messages` will be accessible via the `YourProject.Properties` namespace (where `YourProject` is the name of your project as shown in Solution Explorer).

For example, let's say that you have a resource string named `OperationSucceeded`. You will now be able to access that resource string via:

```cs
MessageBox.Show(YourProject.Properties.Messages.OperationSucceeded);
```

...or, more conveniently:

```cs
using YourProject.Properties;

MessageBox.Show(Messages.OperationSucceeded);
```