# Selecting resource file in code behind at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, resource-files

Suppose I have 2 resources files; one's called `HomeEN.resx` and the other one is called `HomeFR.resx`. I've looked at online tutorials that show how the selection of the resource file is done automatically, based on the user's setting in his browser.

I want to select the resource file at runtime, something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    switch (TheLanguage) {

       case 1:
            // select the English file HomeEN.resx;
            break;

       case 2:
            // select the French file HomeFR.resx;
            break;
    }
}
```

How do I write these statements?

Comment: is this a windows program.. have you looked at `WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources` replacing `WindowsFormsApplication1` with your form name of course..

Comment: No, it's an asp.net website that uses webforms

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct resource files are automatically read by setting the Page's `Culture` and `UICulture` properties. See the [MSDN samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You just need to rename your files to match the expected pattern, `Home.en.resx` and `Home.fr.resx` respectively.

Comment: I don't like these "automatic" sorceries but I guess for this case it'll be OK. Thanks.

Comment: +1 as using standard approach lead to code that will be easier to  read (less surprises). @frenchie if you want to do it hard way check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825433/using-resourcemanager and link to [MSDN: Retrieve Resource Values Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) provided by DJ KRAZE

Comment: For some reason, I must be doing something wrong. Can you take a look at this follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751343/using-localization-and-resource-files-for-asp-net-literal-controls

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = someCulture;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = someCulture;
}
```

After that, if you follow @devio's solution above as well, the resource files will be selected automatically.

Comment: upvoted for the code; what's the difference between .CurrentCulture  and .CurrentUICulture

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access both resources, you can use [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
 ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Strings", typeof(Example).Assembly);
string strDE = rm.GetString("TheNameOfTheResource",  new CultureInfo("de"));
string strES = rm.GetString("TheNameOfTheResource",  new CultureInfo("es"));
```

Comment: what is `typeof(Example).Assembly` ? is the project name?

Comment: I believe it is your .resx filename. +1