# Accessing Resource files from another project of same solution C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, globalization

i have a `Globalization` project under solution, and there is another `MainProject`. Under Globalization there are 2 resource files, `Resources.resx` and `Resources.ar.resx`. Both files have same keys. I want to output the results based on language input i get in model(API).

Declared this as global:
`ResourceManager rm;`

Then i have this function which will check for language input from model, and select resource file accordingly.

```
private void CheckResourceManager(string lang)
{                    
    if (lang =="EN")
    {
        rm = new ResourceManager(
            "Globalization.Resources", 
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
    else
    {
        rm = new ResourceManager(
            "Globalization.Resources.ar", 
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

In the Api function i first check for `CheckResourceManager(model.Language);`
and when there is a message required then: 
`throw new Exception(rm.GetString("WrongUserName"));`

Now issue is `"Globalization.Resources.ar"` in function is not reading the resource, like it can;t locate the file, what should i use here. If i add resource files in same project, then it will work. Advise Please. Thanks

---

Proper approach is from below answer, but for me this method is working fine.

Declared:

```
ResourceManager rm;
CultureInfo originalCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
Assembly localizeAssembly = Assembly.Load("Globalization");
```

Changed the function to:

```
private void CheckResourceManager(string lang)
{
    if (lang =="EN")
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = originalCulture;
        rm = new ResourceManager("Globalization.Resources", localizeAssembly);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar");
        rm = new ResourceManager("Globalization.Resources", localizeAssembly);
    }
}
```

and finally when i need to get some value:

```
throw new Exception(rm.GetString("WrongUserName",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Thank You.

Comment: Now when i added solution name like `PartnerWebApplication.Globalization.Resources.ar` i get following error. `Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "PartnerWebApplication.Globalization.Resources.ar.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "PartnerWebApplication" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.`

Comment: Try : right click on `.resx` file, select `Properties` and set `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `ResourceManager` is to swap to a different culture based on the UI culture of the current thread. You don't need to make a separate function to do it. It won't read a localized culture explicitly - it is convention based. To control the UI culture of the current thread, you need to set it explicitly in an [authorization filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796/181087):

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar")
```

Also, passing the ExecutingAssembly means that you are passing in the *top level* assembly, which most likely is not the assembly your resources are located in. You should use a type within the assembly to get an Assembly instance:

```
new ResourceManager(
        "Globalization.Resources", 
        typeof(ClassWithinResourcesAssembly).Assembly)
```

See the following documentation for more information about how to use the ResourceManager:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408(v=vs.71).aspx
- [Using ResourceManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825433/using-resourcemanager)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes this is right way. though for me i just require few values, so i didnt get into UI Culture etc. changed the function with `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar");
                rm = new ResourceManager("Globalization.Resources", localizeAssembly);` now its fine, for both english and arabic.