# How can I use resources based on localization, without using form's resource files?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, localization, resource-files

Context: This issue applies to a winform project.
I want to have a single resource file, that I can use across all my project. I intend to support multiple languages.

At this moment, I have a file called "strings.resx" in the folder "resources". I can use the values stored in there with the method " My.Resources.strings.

My question is: how can I, for example, create a file with the terms that I want to use in another language (German, Italian, French, etc) and still use only one method, without having to call the method "stringsGerman"/"stringsItalian"/etc?

I don't want to use the resources that are created automatically for the forms, since there are some visual objects that I create in run-time, that are not attached to any form.

Comment: Resource files already do that automatically for you... just name them properly, ex: strings.en.resx

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you want is handled for you by the framework.

You create your default strings in a file called `foo.resx` and then create localized versions in files called `foo.de-DE.resx` or `foo.fr-FR.resx`

You can manually set the current UI culture like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("fr-FR")
```

Then when you call `.GetString` it will pick the appropriate resource file:

```
Dim LocRM As New ResourceManager("WindowsApplication1.WinFormStrings", GetType(Form1).Assembly)
MessageBox.Show(LocRM.GetString("strMessage"))
```

Full detail of how to do this are covered on MSDN: [Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5246631/1497596) and its answers for an approach that does not require you to explicitly create an instance of `ResourceManager`.