# How do i reference to Resources files so i wont have to change the path of the files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create and use resources in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-net)

I use this code but if I run it from another place it obviously will be a wrong path.

```
string strPath = @"C:\Users\perdanny\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PokerBlitz\PokerBlitz\Resources\Cards\" 
    + (suit * 13 + rank).ToString() + ".png";
```

Comment: Properties.Resources.fileName

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already added the file to the resources of the project you can do this by clicking on project -> add existing item. Then find the file in your file system. You can reference the file by using

```
Properties.Resources.fileName
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this:

```
Application.StartupPath + (suit*13+rank).ToString() +".png";
```

probably you need to add some more directorys like \PokerBlitz\Resources\Cards\ I'm not sure about that.

You can read more on this topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)