# Add / switch between embedded / linked resources at running time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, properties

I have the `resources.resx` in my c# code with some strings filled:

```
Text1,"Some Text"
```

and i can call it during running time by

```
Properties.Resources.Text1
```

which results in

```
"Some Text"
```

Now i want to have Text1 a different output (another language for example or something)
so that `Properties.Resources.Text1` results in `"Different Text"`.

How can i achieve this?

EDIT1: i discovered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-net) but i was looking for a different approach with the resource files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use different Resource Files, you can use the ResourceManager:

```
ResourceManager rm;
if (Configuration.Default.Culture == "en-US")
    rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resource1));
else
    // ...
String label = rm.GetString("Text1");
```

Save the the Culture in the User Settings, add a configuration file and define a user variable.

```
Configuration.Default.Culture= "en-US";
Configuration.Default.Save();
```

Updated question according to information

Comment: well that could work, but i was hoping to have at programm startup load a different ressource file or something like that

Comment: if you have different resource files, you could use the resourcemanager. i might be wrong though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx

Comment: the name you chose in the add file wizard when you added your resx file, assuming that you are already using the namespace

Comment: Ah thx, i misspelled the whole time in my code and wondered. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you have to add another resource file for other culture. just look into this thread 
[How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)

**In reference to a comment:**
get the current cultureinfo and load resources like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
if(currentCulture.Name == "en-US")
   Console.WriteLine(resources.Text1);
else if if(currentCulture.Name == "ja-JP")
   Console.WriteLine(resourcesJapan.Text1);
```

Comment: i could add another resource file that was my intention, but how can i tell the code to use the other resource file

Comment: rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resource1)); was the thing i was looking for. But thx anyways