# Using an image in the resource folder in a function which takes file path to image as parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I'm developing a winform application. It has a reference to a dll library. I want to use a function 'PDFImage' in this library. This function is used to put images into a PDF documnent. The function 'PDFimage' has an argument 'FileName' of type String which takes the file location of the image.

Now I have to put the image as a separate file with the .exe file created after the project is built. This is not convenient for me. What I do now is I mention the file name of the image as the function parameter like 'Flower.jpg'. And I have kept the image in the \bin\debug folder.
I don't want to do it like this as this needs the image file to be placed seperately with the executable file.

What I am trying to do is as follows:
I added the image files to the Resources folder as existing item. Now, to call the function PDFImage, I need to pass the file name as argument. How can I do this?

I have the source code of dll with me. Is it better to modify the source code as required and create another dll rather than what I am doing now?

Comment: You should show some code of what isn't working. At a quick glance it sounds like you simply should store the file in a different folder.

Comment: @Foreever You cannot pass an Image Resource as a file path,both differ in Types.The Image Resource is of `Image` type and `filename` is `string` type.If possible try to modify the function parameter and make is as `SomeFunction(Image image)` i.e change the string argument to `Image` type and then you can use the Image Resource as a function parameter.

Comment: @Ek0nomik I'm not sharing any code because I haven't done anything. I Have no idea where to start. I am storing the same in a folder. But don't I need to keep the folder outside of the application while running. As I mentioned, I can only pass the file location of the image to the function. I believe it's not possible to pass the file location of an image in resource folder. Does embedding this images do any good?

Comment: @AviralSingh But Aviral the function belongs to a dll. So, I think I can't modify it as I want.

Comment: @Foreever Well if the code is in a DLL,then sadly you've no other way than to leave your image as a loose resource in some folder.

Comment: @Foreever Although there's no straightforward method to deal with this,however there's a trick you can try to make this work.Try to save the resource as a local file when your application needs it and then you can use the path of this file as a string parameter to that function.

Comment: @AviralSingh I think that is what i am doing now. But I want to distribute the software as a single executable file without any installation. Is it possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37481/discussion-between-aviral-singh-and-foreever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps;

```
    string apppath = Application.StartupPath;
    string resname = @"\Resource.bmp";
    string localfile = "";
    localfile = apppath + resname;//Create the path to this executable.
    //Btw we are going to use the "Save" method of Bitmap class.It
    //takes an absolute path as input and saves the file there.

    //We accesed the Image resource through Properties.Resources.Settings and called Save method
    //of Bitmap class.This saves the resource as a local file in the same folder as this executable.
    Properties.Resources.Image.Save(localfile);

    MessageBox.Show("The path to the local file is : " + Environment.NewLine + localfile + Environment.NewLine +
    "Go and check the folder where this executable is.",
    this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


    //localfile is the path you need to pass to some function like this;
    //SomeClass.Somefunction(localfile);
```

Hope this helps and [here](http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/ff04f5a3) is a sample if you need.

Comment: I see in your sample project you added the image simply, not as embedded. I also added the image as an existing item and didn't make it as an embedded resource. But the file is not listed in Properties. What should I set the build action for this file?

Comment: I found the answer myself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

All you can do with that is get the resource, save it to a file (temporary one may be) and then pass the filename to the function. Most function that take a file in .net also take a stream, so if you have control of both sides, I'd do that and then you don't have to mess about with the file system.