# String template and its arguments

Tags: c#, string

I want to create a string template, part of its content will be completed lately

```
string myTemplete = "This is a template ,which depends on {1} and {2} and {3}"
```

After that I have some functions calls chain and I collect the data from them

```
int arg1 = MyFunc1();
string arg2 = MyFunc2();
string arg3 = MyFunc3();
```

// need to populate the myTemplete with `arg 1` for `{0}`, arg2 for `{1}`, `arg3` for `{2}`

How can I do it?
The template I build is long and in used in many places so don`t want to 
make something like that

```
int arg1 = MyFunc1();
string arg2 = MyFunc2();
string arg3 = MyFunc3();
string myData = string.Format("This is a template ,which depends on {1} and {2} and {3}"
,arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Comment: Uhm... put the template string inside a constant (or, even better, into [a resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-net), so that it can be localized) and then call `string.Format(MyTemplate, MyFunc1(), MyFunc2(), MyFunc3())`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want a reproductive string

```
public static class MyTemplates
{
    public static string MyTemplate(object arg1,object arg2,object arg3)
    {
     return string.Format("This is a template ,which depends on {0} and {1} and {2}",arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
}
```

then simply call

```
string mytemplete = MyTemplates.MyTemplate(MyFunc1(), MyFunc2(),MyFunc3());
```

EDIT: 
Changed the string to object as proposed by Tim Schmelter and string format numbers changed due to the copy paste I did

Comment: Change `{1} and {2} and {3}` to `{0} and {1} and {2}`, otherwise it will throw a `FormatException`. I would also allow object as argument since `String.Format` supports it also.

Comment: sorry, simply copy pasted that :s; changed according to your proposition