# c# nunit: how to access the NUnitProject properties from code?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, automated-tests

I want to do this:

in nunit, go to:
project > cofigurations 
and choose  a configuration file by name, such as :

"firefox"
"chrome"

in each of these files, I want to add a custom property: browser.

crude example of the file:

```
<NUnitProject>
<settings, etc....

<browser = "firefox">
</NUnitProject>
```

in my code, I want to access this config file, and read the browser property.

Comment: Did you try anything? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/q/90697/3124333

Comment: I am hoping that nunit has an object model by which I can read values from the current configuration file that nunit is using.