# MVVM+WPF. How to add a file into deployment package

Tags: wpf, mvvm, deployment, visual-studio-2015

I have a WPF application structured according the MVVM pattern. I wish to set the application background image at runtime, loading a file stored in MyProjectView/images/background.jpg. So, in MyProjectViewModel layer I wrote a procedure to load the background image

```
        Public Sub LoadBackground()
        Dim fs As New FileStream("images/background.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        img = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
        fs.Read(img, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
        End Sub
```

This code work only in the Debug mode. When I deploy my application, no background is loaded, because the image file is not loaded into the deployed folder "images". I tried to set the "Action" property of the file to "EmbeddedResource", but nothing happens.
how can I do to add the background.jpg file into my deployment package?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Build Action to **Content** and the Copy to Output Directory property to **Copy if newer**.

This will copy both the "images" folder and the file to the output folder of the .exe when you build the application.