# c# cannot call Property.Resouce

Tags: c#

I stored some .wav files in the resource folder, but I don't know what the type would it be after `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("A.wav")`

So I called

```
MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("A.wav").GetType().ToString());
```

However, it give me an exception on 
`Properties.Resources`:

> error CS1061: 'PropertyStore' does not contain a definition for 'Resources' and no extension method 'Resources' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyStore' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks for any help!

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

The answer for this problem is as what Amy provided.

stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/…

The resources folder should been added in property tab but not do it manually.

Comment: A resources *folder*?  Or a resources *file*?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-net

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your `Resources.resx` file is located in a filesystem directory (or project folder) named `Resources`, so MSBuild/ResXGenerator will generate your strongly-typed `class Resources` inside a new namespace that matches the folder path - but this is a problem because you have a local class member also named `Properties` and that's what's causing the error.

I recommend changing the namespace the `class Resources` is generated in.

1. Select `Properties/Resources.resx` in the Solution Explorer
2. Open the Visual Studio Properties inspector.
3. Provide a different namespace in the "Custom tool namespace" field.

A partial cause of this confusion is how in .NET both types (`class Resources`) and public members (`YourClass.Resources`) are both in `PascalCase` which means it's impossible to differentiate by eyesight-alone if an identifier refers to a type or a member. (In Java members are always in `camelCase`). If `YourClass.Properties` is an instance member I recommend adopting the convention of always prefixing local instance member access with `this.`.