# Where to save the private key that is used to generate and validate the token?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api, jwt, token

I'm using a private key to generate and validate the token. I'll be using this private key in 3 different .cs files. 
Right now, it's hard-coded in these 3 files.

My question is, Where to save this private key in the project. (not DB or Azure).

Thanks!

Comment: You can save the key in your configuration files. appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the key will not change. You can create a resource file for it. This way your key is not readable in production. At least not easy as store it in config. Find more information about resources here: [How to create and use resources in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-net)

Comment: Keys should regularly be rotated, and there should be a way to revoke/replace compromised keys.